# Pikaday not loading for other OctoberCMS admin

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I as super administrator and site owner is able to load the Pikaday for date selector but other site administrators are unable to. They are able to load the time selector though.

This is despite setting them as super admin or giving more/all privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking their language / time preferences for their account under backend preferences. Also check the browser developed console and see if there are any errors reported

Comment: Thanks! The suggestion worked! Is there a way to set the default language for any new administrator?

Comment: Yes, in config/cms.php there is the backendTimezone value, just set that. Always use UTC in config/app.php timezone but you can set the default backend timezone in config/cms.php